# Are stats on 10m page realtime?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Stats displayed at https://stackoverflow.com/10m are dynamic. Are these real time stats and how are they queried over network?

Comment: Web sockets. Have you tried looking at the page source?

Comment: And are they real time?

Comment: The JavaScript module is called "realtime.js", but I cannot guarantee the data is actually gathered in real time -- it could lag a little behind the actual information. An SE dev could tell for sure.

Comment: It's probably "good enough to be called real time by anyone not afraid of getting corrected (in a very annoyed tone) by people who are into [Real Time Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)."

Comment: I would think that they are as current as your info is, what I mean is the indicator someone left you a comment, or changed rep etc..

Comment: can anyone provide query with which i can verify the data?(https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Comment: Must-read follow-on to @Pekka웃's point: [**It Isn’t Your Father’s Realtime Anymore**](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1117409)

Comment: @vaibhavmagar from the [data.se FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) "The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC." So the data.se will not be anywhere close to real time.

Comment: It is caching .

Answer (score 13):

That page, as well as most others with similarly updated information are using [Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

The information is not likely '[real time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing)', but it is likely pretty current.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. I could use web sockets to retrieve information one year old. Web sockets is a technology, I think the question is more conceptual, like: is it an estimate based on the trends of the time series or is it a count based on the database?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I think the second line answers the question. Probably the first and second line should be swapped to get through perfect answer correctness.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão OP also asks "*how* are they queried", isn't "Web Sockets" an answer to that?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: It helps if you read the WHOLE answer before commenting.

Comment: @GEOCHET, What makes "likely pretty current" factually more correct than *likely pretty old*, *likely pretty BS* or *likely I don't know and I just wrote likely pretty current*?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: What difference does it make? Did you read the question? It asked if it was real time. And the answer is that is not likely to be real time. What part are you having difficulty in understanding?

Comment: -1. It's fine to be pedantic about computing terms, but the OP was not using one. "[Real time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time)" is an ordinary English phrase. (If the OP had asked about swift updates, would you reply that the updates are not generated by [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28programming_language%29)?) If you remove that pedantry, then the rest of your answer amounts to "yeah, probably".

Comment: Updated from where? A linear regression on SE server?

Comment: Or one of you could have posted that the page source used `StackExchange.realtime.init` instead of bitching back and forth about it. Jesus Christ in a chicken basket.

Comment: If you're all going to be pedantic then no its not real-time because nothing is. When someone speaks you don't hear it in real-time there is a very very minuscule delay before you hear it. All silliness aside if you just think about what the page is trying to show, it's clear that the information would be very close to *current* otherwise what is the point.

Comment: I like how so many people are trying to say that my answer is wrong, but they have yet to provide one.